# Change dropdown background color in CSS

Tags: javascript, otrs

I am currently trying to customise OTRS 5 and have got most things how I want them by creating a custom skin and overriding the default CSS. However, all of the dropdown menus are orange on hover but this seems to be set somewhere in the Javascript files and not in raw CSS. Does anyone know which files I need to change to override this background color to another?

Thanks

Comment: You could use chrome developer tools to add a breakpoint on mouseover and identify the source of the change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's still pure CSS here!

You'd want to use these CSS selectors in your skin, the first one is the hover color and the second one is the class for the currently active navigation button.

```
#Navigation > li:hover {
    border-color: blue;
}

#Navigation > .Selected {
    border-color: green;
}
```

[image]